# Insert custom html into the filter area of the Select2 js

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Now I have a task to append some html (div with additional filter) into the filter area. Unfotrunally I couldn't find some options which allowed it.
Is there way to do it?

[There is an example what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooe2q.png)

Comment: Did you try something already?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I've got no clue as to what you are asking.

Comment: can you share code or fiddle with us?

Comment: I have provided an example what I need. Please, see edited description.